# How to validate google reCaptcha on server side?

Tags: javascript, php, magento-1.9, recaptcha

I implemented reCaptcha. After the "I am not a robot" checkbox is clicked, a token is getting generated from google.

Client side (js)

```
    function checkCaptchaAndSubscribe(thisContext)
    {
        var captchaResponse = grecaptcha.getResponse();

        if (captchaResponse == "") {
            $captchaRequired.css('display', 'block');
            return false;
        }

        grecaptcha.reset();
        $captchaRequired.css('display', 'none');

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/black_newsletter2go/index/verify",
            method: "POST",
            async: "true",
            data: {
                recaptchaResponse: captchaResponse
            },
            success: function(response) {

                $statusContainer.show();

                if (response != "success") {
                    $status.html("<h2 class='nl2go_h2'>Die Captcha Validierung ist fehlgeschlagen!</h2>");
                    return false;
                }

                subscribe(thisContext);
            }
        });
    }
```

I send the token to my server by using ajax and validate it there like this:

Server side (php):

```
    public function verifyAction()
    {
        $captchaResponse = $this->getRequest()->getParam('recaptchaResponse');

        if (!isset($captchaResponse) || empty($captchaResponse)) {
            return "captcha response is empty";
        }

        $secretKey = Mage::Helper("recaptcha")->getSecretKey();

        $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
        $data = array(
            'secret' => $secretKey,
            'response' => $captchaResponse,
        );

        // use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
        $options = array(
            'http' => array(
                'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query($data)
            )
        );

        $context  = stream_context_create($options);

        $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
        $result = json_decode($result);

        //var_dump($result);
        //exit();

        if ($result->success
                && (strpos(Mage::getBaseUrl(), $result->hostname) !== false)) {
            echo "success";
        } else {
            echo "fail";
        }
    }
```

This is the output of the object $result

[image]

It returns `success` if the checks were successfull, otherwise `fail`.

But is this enough? What if the attacker uses a HTTP proxy like burpsuite to change the response to `success`? Then he can bypass my checks and always get through? Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It uses a key pair to encrypt/decrypt the info. So it's sending the info encrypted. That's why it can't be tempered with, but of course, that means you must make sure to not get the private key stolen.

There the server knows and saves the state in its storage so if the client tries to use it as "success" when it was "fail", the server will know, no matter what. So for the hacker to change the value for the client is not likely to do much, it will depend on your code, of course. If you are using that reCAPTCHA to log the user in, then obviously that login attempt will fail on the server side if the reCAPTCHA returned "fail". So whether the client is told "success" or not, it still won't be logged in. The client should never be the keeper of such a state since it can't be trusted (it can always have tainted data.)

It works in a way similar to what you'd do between a browser and a server using HTTPS.

The communication between your client and your server should also be on HTTPS to avoid some easier man in the middle (MITM) problems. However, it is always possible to have someone who becomes a proxy, which is how most MITM work, and in that case, whatever you're doing can be changed by the MITM.

The one thing that the MITM can't do is create a valid certificate for the final destination, however. In that sense, there is a protection, but many people don't verify certificates each time they connect to a website. One technique, though, has been for MITM to not give you HTTPS, only him and your server would use HTTPS and the client would remain on HTTP. Although your code could detect such, obviously the MITM can also change that code. Similarly, having a cookie set with `Http-Only` and `Secure` can enhance the security, but that too can be intercepted by a MITM.

Since the MITM can completely change your scripts, there is pretty much nothing you can do on the client's side that would help detect such a problem and on the server side, you will receive hits that look like what the client sent to you. So again, no real way to detect a MITM.

[There is a post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/110599/detect-man-in-the-middle-on-server-side-for-https) that was asking that very question: could I detect an MITM from the server side? It's not impossible, but it's rather tricky. There are solutions being put in place by new implementations/extensions to the normal HTTP solution, but those require an additional application that connects  to a different system and there is no reason why such could not also be proxied by a MITM once enough people use such solutions.

Comment: My server communicates to the google server and then decides wheter or not it should return the string `success` or `fail` as you can see in my code. Concern: Attackers could catch the response from MY SERVER, change it from `fail` to `success` and play it back in, so they will always get `success`.

Comment: @Black I added some info about a MITM attack, which is what would be required to make the change you are talking about. There isn't much chance that a server could detect/prevent it. I put a link to a page with an answer on that.

Answer (score 0):

The result comes from an URL that is owned by Google. 
If user tampered with what is being send to your php script - then the google webservice will return a failure and you won't pass such request through.

Comment: Yes I know, but what If the user tampers with the response from my server? They could intercept it and change `fail` to `success`. Thats my concern.

Comment: it is a https request which contains your secret key that user has no access to. 
It's not "possible" to be done.

Comment: No, my server talks to the google server and then decides wheter or not it should return the string `success` or `fail`. Attackers could catch the response from MY SERVER, change it and play it back in, so they will always get `success`.

Comment: oh I see what you're asking about now. I misunderstood you

What you want to do is to invalidate user session or token or whatever you use as soon as you get failure from google service.